# What is the proper way to serialize/deserialize a dictionary that contains boxed elements

Tags: c#, .net, generics, serialization, xmlserializer

I am making a generic library that allows saving/loading of settings (meant to be used by game mods).
The structure is simply a disctionary of Category that holds a KV pair of Setting Name:Value.

Initially I was just using a Generic Nested Dictionary:

`private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> Categories`

Note that it stores the value boxed in an object.

The watered down version is straight forward. User passes in the values and an action that gets called when the setting changes.

```
public override RegisterSetting<T>(string category, string name, T defaultValue, Action<T> onValueUpdated)
{
   T value;
   if (!_settings.Get<T>(category, name, out value))
   {
      _settings.Set(category, name, defaultValue);
      _settings.Save(_instance); //This does the XML serialization
      value = defaultValue;
   }
   onValueUpdated(value);
   return;
}

public void Set(string category, string key, object obj)
{
   if (!Categories.ContainsKey(category)) Categories.Add(category, new Dictionary<string, object>());
      Categories[category][key] = obj;
}

public object Get<T>(string category, string key)
{
   object _value;
   if (Categories.TryGetValue(category, out Dictionary<string, object> setting) && setting.TryGetValue(key, out _value))
   {
      value = (T)_value;
      return true;
   }

   value = default;
   return false
}
```

Here's where my question comes in. I need to serialize/deserialize this and I'm also displaying a GUI which displays the values and allows users to change them.

To serialize this, I convert it to a `List<Category> Categories` so I can use XmlSerializer

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath))
{
   var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
   serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
}
```

Here's the structure:

```
public class Category
{
   public Category() { }
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string Key;
   public List<Setting> Value;
}

public class Setting
{
   public string Key;
   public object Value;
}
```

This all works, and I'm now at the point where I want to build the GUI, but I feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. For one, all the values are boxed, and two, I have to convert Dictionary to List and back again for serialization. All the dicitonary is doing is keeping categories and settings name unique.

Now that I'm at the GUI stage, because all the values are boxed. I have to foreach(setting.GetType()) and then display the appropriate control for that type.

I started going down the path of having a base class for Setting that stores the boxed value and name, and a derived generic T class that stores the value strongly typed.

```
public class SettingBase
{
   public string Key;
   private object BoxedValue;
}

public class Setting<T> : SettingBase
{
   public T Value 
   {
      get => (T) BoxedValue;
      set 
      {
         BoxedValue = Value
      }
   }
}
```

I was hoping the GUI class would just have a set of overlaoded methods to draw the right control, but I don't quite understand if and how this will get serialized or how it solved my issue, because now I will have a dictionary of SettingBase and I still don't have the type to pass to the overloaded methods. Before I go any further down this rathole, any advice?

Although this perhaps seems very specific, my title is based on the fact I believe I'm trying to fundamentally understand how to best store and serialize/deseriable a dataset that contains mixed types as runtime.

I'm foced to use .NET Framework 3.5 BTW. Not sure if another serialization method such as DataContract helps here to prevent the Dictionary<->List conversion.